# compressjs.sh option to combine only not minify

Tags: javascript, bash, minify

I am using [CompressJS.sh](https://github.com/dfsq/compressJS.sh) and it works great!

Is there a way that I can modify the bash file to stop it from minifying the javascript file?

Currently I'm in the development stage, if the file is minified the variables has been replaced so I cannot debug properly.

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

You could just use a simple, command-line-compatible script while developing, then swap in the real thing for production:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
length=$(($#-1))
INFILES=${@:1:$length}
OUTFILE="${!#}"
cat $INFILES > $OUTFILE
```